# The best approach to publish SNS Topic with existing Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, amazon-sns

I already built the spring batch job application that generates the csv file. and the csv file contains a very long list of objects. and I also want to send this list of objects via email using AWS SNS topic. And I am having some thoughts of how to implement it.

and what i want is only one email that contains all the list of objects. not multiple.

1. using the existing ItemWriter class, call the function to send the sns topic.

```
class StudentWriter implements ItemWriter<Student> {
  @Autowired 
  ResourceLoader resourceLoader

  WritableResource resource
  OutputStreamWriter writer
  CSVPrinter csvPrinter
 
  void prepare() {
    this.resource = this.resourceLoader("s3://output.csv")
    this.writer = new OutputStreamWriter(this.resource.outputStream)
    this.csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(this.writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)
  }

  @Override
  void write(List<? extends Student> items) throws Exception {
    this.csvPrinter.with { printer -> 
      items.each { it -> 
        printer.printRecord(it.id, it.name, it.subjects)
      }
    }
  }

  @AfterStep
  void afterStep() {
    this.csvPrinter.close()
    // call function to publish to sns topic
  }
}
```

I had to add afterStep function and close the csvPrinter as it was not writing anything to csv file(even not creating it). and when csvPrinter is closed, it generates csv file and write the content to it after the the last batch.
by that I mean, I could call the function to publish to sns topic. However, I have to access to s3 bucket and read the csv file just generated and publish it as content.

2. store the list of objects in a memory or somewhere and when the function is called to publish to sns topic, read the list.

this would be similar to the option 1 i guess, but I am not sure where to store the objects. in every batch when the write function is called, i have to store each objects and at the end of batch, i have to read them all and publish it. but I do not know where to store them and get quick access.

3. create completely new resource, maybe lambda

it would be simplest approach i believe. but it is creating a new additional resource, meaning it would cost in addition. and if spring batch could handle SNS, then it would be a total waste. but otherwise, i wanna do this way.

Would you please give me some advice to it?
I am not sure what is the best, but I assume the option3 is not good.
I would like to go for option 2, but not sure where I can store the obects and publish it after the batch job is done.
FYI, language used is groovy.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a `CompositeItemWriter` with two delegates? One delegate writes to S3 and the other to SNS.

Comment: No, I actually decided to use tasklet for sns and chunk for writing csv. but if i knew it before I would have gone for that. I appreciate your comment. for the future reference, i will still read it. thanks a lot